# ADF expression adddays() giving error "The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format"

Tags: azure-data-factory

for ADF parameter I provided `@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5),'yyyy-MM-01'))` in Debug/trigger but I get this error.

In function 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string '@{formatDateTime(adddays(utcnow(),-5),'yyyy-MM-01')) ' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format

I have also tried these and it does not work.

```
@adddays(utcnow('yyyy-MM-dd'),1)
@{formatDateTime(adddays('2021-02-09T08:40:00.4158787Z',-5),'yyyy-MM-01'))
@{formatDateTime(adddays('2021-02-09T08:40:00.4158787Z',-5),'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fffffffK'))
```

Comment: Your first expression should be:  `@formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-5),'yyyy-MM-01')`.  Remove the starting curly bracket and one additional trailing bracket.

Comment: I tried that too and it was not working. The issue was the '@' expansion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual Debug or trigger will not expand with "@" . Give the end result directly eg: "2021-02-09T08:40:00.4158787Z". To test expressions use this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372404/adf-testing-expression-function).

Answer (score 2):

Your first expression should be: `@formatDateTime(addDays(utcnow(),-5),'yyyy-MM-01')`. Remove the starting curly bracket and one additional trailing bracket.

It's the same for the others.  ADF expression always start with @ symbols, curly brackets are used in [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-expression-builder#string-interpolation) and of course must match up.