# ADF testing expression function

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a way to test expression functions in ADF?

eg: I want to add this expression in my trigger parameter : `@{adddays(utcNow(),-10)}`

The only way to test it is by creating a 1 min trigger and see if it executes. The same expression will not work on debug or manual trigger as the text boxes there will not expand.

Is there any other way to test these easily?

Comment: I usually test them in a `Set Variable` task which is a good way to do it, or sometimes log them via the Stored Proc activity as a parameter.  Make sense?  I can post answer with screenprint etc if that will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to test ADF expressions (not including Mapping Data Flows) is to use a Set Variable activity.  Just create a test variable and copy the expression into it and run the pipeline.  You can then view the output from the expression in the Output window:

[image: ADF expressions]

Click the Output button on the Output menu once your pipeline has completed to view the contents of the variable:

[image: Output]

Comment: This works fine but the second set variable is unnecessary in my case.

Comment: Great, thanks.  Don't be afraid to upvote too!  Is there another ADF question you need help with?  I saw you posted a couple.  There are a few ppl on here now that help with these, like myself, Joseph Xu, Steve Zhao and Leon Yue.